# Hashtable vs ConcurrentHashMap, is the answer correct, why?

Tags: java

I read somewhere about replacing Hashtable with ConcurrentHashMap:

*Since Hashtable locks whole Map instead of a portion of Map, compound operations like if(Hashtable.get(key) == null) put(key, value) works in Hashtable but not in concurrentHashMap. instead of this use putIfAbsent() method of ConcurrentHashMap*

Since there is a gap between the get and the put, why does the hashtable work?

*if(Hashtable.**get**(key) == null) **put**(key, value)*

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: Where did you read that about Hashtable? It's wrong. `if(hashtable.get(key) == null) hashtable.put(key, value)` will not always work correctly. The thread can still be interrupted between the if-expression and the put statement.

Comment: It doesn't, whoever wrote that was wrong. You need `putIfAbsent()` or `computeIfAbsent()` or one of the other methods that are atomic.

Comment: Not official Javadoc? Source? https://www.demo2s.com/java/java-interview-question-replace-hashtable-with-concurrenthashmap-in-ja.html

Comment: *"The thread can still be interrupted between the if-expression and the put statement."*  - In two respects.  1) The thread could be preempted by the thread scheduler.  2) A 2nd thread on another core could grab the lock ... which is released at the end of the `get` and reacquired at the beginning of the `put`.

Comment: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/11/collection-interview-questions-answers.html#axzz6w4DsCF9X 
Look under #17. I trust the author though.

Comment: *"I trust the author though."* - You shouldn't.  You really shouldn't!

Comment: @wang1908: having read just that one question: you should not trust that author. The information is *highly misleading* to say the least and I suspect that a lot of it is outright wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In your question you quoted this as fact:

> "Since `Hashtable` locks whole `Map` instead of a portion of `Map`, compound operations like `if (hashtable.get(key) == null) hashtable.put(key, value)` works in `Hashtable` but not in `ConcurrentHashMap`."

Unfortunately it is incorrect.  That code using `Hashtable` does NOT work ... in the sense that the author means.

Yes, the `get` and `put` methods *do* lock the entire table.  But these methods only hold the lock for the duration of the operation.  Between the `get` and `put`, the above code will release the lock on `hashTable` and then reacquire it.

This means that a second thread could call `put` to put a different value for the key.  The sequence might look like this:

1. thread A - `hashtable.get("a")` -> `null`
2. thread B - `hashtable.get("a")` -> `null`
3. thread B - `hashtable.put("a", 1)`
4. thread A - `hashtable.put("a", 2)`

And we have called `put` twice with different values for the same key.

Which thread will "win"?  In general, we can't say.  It depends on the precise timing, and other things.  It is not predictable.

So, if the *intended behavior* is that the first thread to call `get` on the key should always win, then this is not a thread-safe implementation.